# org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException : Cannot add a query whose types conflict with an existing query

Tags: java, validation, jpa, jpql

I've a Java EE assignment which is based on an environment built with GlassFish, Maven and Derby. I can build the user interface, but when I click the "create" button, it throws an `org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException`.

The stack trace is:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7092] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot add a query whose types conflict with an existing query. Query To Be Added: [ReadAllQuery(name="findAllOrders" referenceClass=Order jpql="SELECT b FROM Order b")] is named: [findAllOrders] with arguments [[]].The existing conflicting query: [ReadAllQuery(name="findAllOrders" referenceClass=Order jpql="SELECT b FROM Order b")] is named: [findAllOrders] with arguments: [[]].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.existingQueryTypeConflict(ValidationException.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.addQuery(AbstractSession.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.addQuery(AbstractSession.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.processJPAQueries(AbstractSession.java:2175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
    at work2.ass2.BootEJB.createBoot(BootEJB.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5367)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:801)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:862)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:801)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:371)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5339)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5327)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 45 more
```

The entity is:

```
    package work2.ass2;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    @NamedQueries({
                @NamedQuery(name = "findAllBoots", query = "SELECT b FROM Boot b"),
                @NamedQuery(name = "searchingBoots", query = "SELECT b FROM Boot b b.title= :pint")})
    public class Boot {

        // ======================================
        // =             Attributes             =
        // ======================================
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String title;
        private Float price;
        @Column(length = 2000)
        private String description;
        private String producer;
        private String color;
        private Integer size;
        private Boolean illustrations;

        // ======================================
        // =            Constructors            =
        // ======================================

        public Boot() {
        }

        public Boot(String title, Float price, String description, String color, Integer size, Boolean illustrations) {
            this.title = title;
            this.price = price;
            this.description = description;
            this.producer = producer;
            this.color = color;
            this.size = size;
            this.illustrations = illustrations;
        }

        // ======================================
        // =          Getters & Setters         =
        // ======================================
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

          public String getProducer() {
            return producer;
        }

        public void setProducer (String producer) {
            this.producer = producer;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public Float getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(Float price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Integer getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setSize(Integer size) {
            this.size= size;
        }

        public Boolean getIllustrations() {
            return illustrations;
        }

        public void setIllustrations(Boolean illustrations) {
            this.illustrations = illustrations;
        }

        // ======================================
        // =         hash, equals, toString     =
        // ======================================

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Boot");
            sb.append("{id=").append(id);
            sb.append(", Producer='").append(producer).append('\'');
            sb.append(", title='").append(title).append('\'');
            sb.append(", price=").append(price);
            sb.append(", description='").append(description).append('\'');
            sb.append(", color='").append(color).append('\'');
            sb.append(", size=").append(size);
            sb.append(", illustrations=").append(illustrations);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

The service is:

```
    package work2.ass2;

    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import javax.persistence.Query;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * @author Antonio Goncalves
     *         APress Book - Beginning Java EE 6 with Glassfish
     *         http://www.apress.com/
     *         http://www.antoniogoncalves.org
     *         --
     */
    @Stateless
    public class BootEJB {

        // ======================================
        // =             Attributes             =
        // ======================================

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "work2PU")
        private EntityManager em;

        // ======================================
        // =           Public Methods           =
        // ======================================

        public List<Boot> findBoots() {
            Query query = em.createNamedQuery("findAllBoots");
            return query.getResultList();
        }

        public List <Boot> findBootByTitle(String sBoot) {
            Query query1 = em.createNamedQuery("searchingBoots");
            query1.setParameter("pint",sBoot);
            return query1.getResultList();
        }

        public Boot createBoot(Boot boot) {
            em.persist(boot);
            return boot;
        }
    }


    package work2.ass2;

    import javax.ejb.EJB;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * @author Antonio Goncalves
     *         APress Book - Beginning Java EE 6 with Glassfish
     *         http://www.apress.com/
     *         http://www.antoniogoncalves.org
     *         --
     */
    @ManagedBean
    (name = "bootController")
    @RequestScoped
    public class BootController {

        // ======================================
        // =             Attributes             =
        // ======================================

        @EJB
        private BootEJB bootEJB;

        private Boot boot = new Boot();
        private List<Boot> bootList = new ArrayList<Boot>();
        private List<Boot> sBootList = new ArrayList<Boot>();

        // ======================================
        // =           Public Methods           =
        // ======================================

        public String doCreateBoot() {
            boot = bootEJB.createBoot(boot);
            bootList = bootEJB.findBoots();
            return "success";
        }
        public String doSearchBoot(String sBoot) {


                    sBootList = bootEJB.findBootByTitle(sBoot);
                    return "findingBoots.xhtml";
        }

        // ======================================
        // =          Getters & Setters         =
        // ======================================


        public Boot getBoot() {
            return boot;
        }

        public void setBoot(Boot boot) {
            this.boot = boot;
        }

        public List<Boot> getBootList() {
            return bootList;
        }

        public void setBootList(List<Boot> bootList) {
    this.bootList = bootList;
        }
        public List<Boot> getsBootList() {
                return bootList;
        }

        public void setsBootList(List<Boot> sBootList) {
                this.sBootList = sBootList;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The *full* stack trace would help...

Comment: Ican not understand the stack trace I am biginner bu t I will post the stack trace

Comment: The real exception seems to be: `[EclipseLink-7092]`: "Cannot add a query whose types conflict with an existing query. Query To Be Added: [ReadAllQuery(name="findAllOrders" referenceClass=Order jpql="SELECT b FROM Order b")]". This is about an **Order** object, not a **Boot**.

Comment: Thanks but how can I make ti right? I do have not very much basic knowledge about query. Thanks

Comment: I believe the answer by unwichtich will solve the issue. This error message sometimes occurs when deployment fails, but the app continues on and tries to obtain the EntityManager anyway - this causes it repeat parts of the deployment process, specifically processing named queries it might already have processed, making it appear as if there are duplicates.  You need to look in the deployment logs for warnings and errors that prevented successful deployment, or upgrade to a later version (such as 2.4.2 or 2.5) where there the error will be made more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in the 2nd `NamedQuery`...it is missing the `WHERE`.

Try it like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "searchingBoots", query = "SELECT b FROM Boot b WHERE b.title= :pint")})
```